# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dispatch-queue

How do I fix this code so it doesn't give the error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context?

```
var int = 0
while int < 100 {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + int) { // change 2 to desired number of seconds
            // do stuff
        }
        int += 1
}
```

The code is being run in dispatch queue in applicationDidEnterBackground, in an attempt to make text to speech work in the background.

Answer (score 9):

The **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context** error is stemming from two facts:

1. Swift doesn't know how to add a `DispatchTime` and an `Int`.
2. Because of fact 1, Swift doesn't know how to interpret `.now()`.

---

**Swift doesn't know how to add a `DispatchTime` and an `Int`**

This can be demonstrated with:

```
let t = DispatchTime.now() + Int(5)
```

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DispatchTime' and 'Int'

but Swift does know how to add a `DispatchTime` and a `Double`:

```
let t = DispatchTime.now() + Double(5)
```

This compiles fine with no errors.

> So why does `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5)` work?

In this case, Swift is interpreting the integer literal `5` as a `Double`.  Type `Double` conforms to the protocol `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` which is what allows you to do:

```
let d: Double = 5
```

So in this case, it works because `5` isn't an `Int`, it's a `Double`.

**Because of fact 1, Swift doesn't know how to interpret `.now()`**

When you tried to add an `Int` to `.now()`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + int)
```

the Swift type inference system got confused.  Swift knows that it wants to pass a `DispatchTime` to `asyncAfter(deadline:)`, but it no longer could figure out what `.now()` is because there is no way to add a `DispatchTime` and an `Int` to get a `DispatchTime`, it decided that `.now()` was not a `DispatchTime` but some other unknown type.  So the ambiguous error message is coming from Swift's inability to determine what `.now()` is.

If you make that explicit by saying `DispatchTime.now()`, then you get a more sensible error:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + int)
```

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DispatchTime' and 'Int'

As further evidence of this theory, if you provide Swift a way to add a `DispatchTime` and an `Int`, Swift is happy with your original code:

```
func +(_ lhs: DispatchTime, _ rhs: Int) -> DispatchTime {
    return lhs + .seconds(rhs)
}
```

> So what is this `.seconds()` stuff?  And how does it help solve the error?

There is a related `enum` type `DispatchTimeInterval` that has cases `microseconds(Int)`, `milliseconds(Int)`, `nanoseconds(Int)`, `seconds(Int)` and `never`.  Swift knows how to add a `DispatchTime` and a `DispatchTimeInterval`, so Swift is able to interpret `.seconds(int)` as a `DispatchTimeInterval` which then allows it to interpret `.now()` as a `DispatchTime`.

> Why did the Swift designers choose to let you add a `Double` to a `DispatchTime` and not an `Int`?

You'd have to ask them.  I suspect they chose the `Double` out of convenience (allowing literal values such as `2.5` to be used) and because it allows you to specify time intervals smaller than one second.  The `Int` doesn't give you any extra capabilities (except of course for eliminating this very confusing error message).

**Conclusion**

The error is coming from the fact that you confused Swift's type inference system by trying to add an `Int` to a `DispatchTime`.

The fixes as the other answers suggested:

1. Use a `Double`.

   **or**
2. Use the `DispatchTimeInterval` `enum` to explicitly note what your `Int` represents.  In your case `.seconds(int)`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a *double* variable to add to the `.now()`.

```
var delay: Double = 0
while delay < 100 {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) { // change 2 to desired number of seconds
            // do stuff
        }
        int += 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `DispatchTime` math with literals

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2)
```

but not with an `Int` variable, that's the ambiguity. There is a `DispatchTimeInterval` enum to be able to pass an `Int` variable

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(int))
```

Comment: Hi. I was actually waiting for someone more experienced to answer :D. Why can you add a `Double` variable to `DispatchTime`?

Comment: Good question, next question . I have no idea particularly the raw value of `DispatchTime` is even `UInt64`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, for me this code works

```
        let delay = Int64(120)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(delay), repeats: false) { (timer) in
                // do stuff
            }
        }
```